# iOS storing and querying audio files on remote server

Tags: ios, audio, download

I need to store and constantly update thousands of audio clips and for use with an iOS app.   I also need to store metadata with each audio clip.  Based on user inputs I need to query the database that the clips are held in and download several clips to a temporary folder in the app so they can be played.

It doesn't seem that a service like Parse can store large audio files.

What would be the best approach for something like this?